# Си. Алгебраическая проблема

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы

Даны числа d — степень полинома, массив K—коэффициенты полинома P(x) и число а.
Требуется найти и вывести коэффициенты произведения полинома P(x) на (x–a).
Input
Со стандартного устройства ввода в первой строке вводится целое число
d (1 <= d <= 1000) степень полинома, во второй строке вводятся (d+1) целых чисел —
массив K (-1000 <= Ki <= 1000)—коэффициенты при членах в полиноме от старшей
степени к младшей. В третьей вводится число а (-1000 <= a <= 1000).
Output
Требуется найти и вывести коэффициенты произведения полинома P(x) на (x–a).
Выводить пробел в конце строки не нужно.
Sample Input

```
2
2 0 3
-4
```

Sample Output

```
2 8 3 12
```

мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main() {
    int *P,*R;
    int i,n,a, m;
    scanf ("%d", &n);
   
    P = (int*)malloc(n+1 * sizeof(int));
    R = (int*)malloc(n+2 * sizeof(int));
 
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++)  scanf ("%d", &P[n-i] ); 
    scanf ("%d", &a);
    
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++) R[i+1]=P[i];
    R[0]=0;
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++) R[i]=R[i]-P[i]*a;
    for (i=0; i<=n+1; i++)
    {
        m= R[n+1-i];
        printf("%d", m);
      
       if (i < n+1)  printf(" ");  
    }
    
     free (P);
    free (R);
  
    return 0;
}
```

Проходит только на 20 баллов из 100

Comment: А в чем смысл второго цикла?

Comment: Дайте URL, где она проходит на 20 баллов...

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, то пожалуйста примите его как "Правильный ответ" нажал на галочку слева от ответа, или скажите что не так и я помогу :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю ошибка на этих строчках :)) :

```
P = (int*)malloc(n+1 * sizeof(int));
R = (int*)malloc(n+2 * sizeof(int));
```

Я думаю вы хотели выделить память под `n + 1` и `n + 2` элементов. Если это так то приоритет сложения меньше, чем у умножения.

То есть нужно вот так:

```
P = (int*)malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(int));
R = (int*)malloc((n + 2) * sizeof(int));
```